# Execute Python script (that reads user data on computer) in Google Chrome extension - NPAPI

Tags: python, google-chrome-extension, npapi, cython, firebreath

http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/npapi.html

I have read through this, and am thoroughly confused.  I have built the sample npapi .so plugin from http://www.firebreath.org/display/documentation/Building+on+Linux

Everything worked fine (plugin is installed correctly and recognized) until I went to use it in my popup.html in my unpacked extension, which threw:

```
<embed type="application/x-sample" id="sample">
<script>
console.log((document.getElementById("sample"))().echo("asdf"));
```

*popup.html:18Uncaught ReferenceError: NPObject deleted*

From various testing, it appears calling the constructor on the plugin object throws the error.  I have no idea what's going on here.

**All I really want to do is to compile a .py file using Cython into a .so or .dll, and then be able to call its methods in my extension.**
Does anyone know of an easy way to do this? / Can anyone provide a simple 'hello, world' example of this working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

where is your extra () coming from? Most likely it should be this:

```
console.log(document.getElementById("sample").echo("asdf"));
```

What you were trying to do would probably end up trying to call the "default" method on the NPObject, which is probably nonexistent and will thus throw an exception.

Comment: No dice. `popup.html:18 Uncaught TypeError: Object #<HTMLEmbedElement> has no method 'echo'` I am using the npFBTestPlugin.so built from the examples, and have included it in my manifest.json.

Comment: try using an object tag; embed tags have frequently not worked well for me.  If that's not working, though, then the plugin isn't loading